# Why is Xcode crashing when I try to preview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github, swiftui

Every time I am trying to resume my preview canvas in Xcode I get this annoying error. I tried restarting, moving the project to another location, and changing the preview device. The current project is a fresh one, just started building a view.

Strange thing is that when I run it on the iOS Simulator it works. The app builds successfully. I also noticed that this is only happening when I use source control with my project(GitHub). Not using it is not an option for me.

Let me know if I need to add the whole crash report, because it's very long.

Here is the full crash log
https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/5f8f5c96-7c1e-4eef-b0d7-ed59894a9c30

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't use that before.

Comment: I added an edit

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by preview? Preview a view, swiftUI view, a build?

Comment: I am talking about the Canvas. The preview for a SwiftUI View.

Comment: Are you on an Intel or Apple Silicon device?

Comment: I am on a MBP 14 with M1 Pro

Comment: Try running with Rosetta enabled.

Comment: I just tried. Same thing. It's very strange and annoying.

Comment: At this point, add your code for the particular view you're attempting to preview, or add your most recently added view.

Comment: Sorry to comment so late in this but I am facing the same problem and I can't manage to find a solution. @VladPoncea did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't add your code so I can't help specifically but here are some of the reasons it happened to me in the past:

- If you use an environment object on the view you're previewing and you don't add it to preview, it causes a crash:

  ```
  struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
      static var previews: some View {
          MyView()
              .environmentObject(ViewModel())
      }
  }
  ```
- Sometimes I just add ZStack to it and it magically solves the problem:

  ```
  struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
      static var previews: some View {
          ZStack {
              MyView()
          }  
      }
  }
  ```
- Sometimes It helps to clean the project (command + shift + K) and build again

Basically if your project works in simulator it means there's nothing wrong with it, it builds. The only problem is that you can't use the preview. You probably didn't set it right, it's missing something it needs in order to run properly. Try to figure it out. Or just run on simulator like we did before there was such a thing as previews..

Comment: The ZStack is helping a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It may be late, but this is the correct answer:

You have to expose your Preview to the Environment variable.

You do that by adding the modifier

```
 .environment(ViewModel()) // if ViewModel is the observable object//
```

to the Preview view that it is displaying e.g.,

```
#Preview {
   ContentView()
      .environment(ViewModel())
}
```